# How do I get Raspberry Pi to boot directly into browser?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have put the following line in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file:

```
 chromium--kiosk www.bbc.co.uk
```

However I then get an error at start up:

```
"(chromium:2100): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"
```

If I set the Pi to boot into OS at startup it chromium never appears but if I start a terminal window it suddenly opens chromium in kiosk mode and with the specified web page!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Trying adding `startx` one line before `chromium--kiosk www.bbc.co.uk` in your `~/.bashrc`. Your `.bashrc` file is read every time you start `bash` for example when the pi doesn't take you straight to the desktop you are in a `bash` shell but you have no `xserver` running so the chrome window cannot be displayed. So start the windowing environment in your `.bashrc` with `startx` before you launch `chrome`.

Comment: I have put that line in but it still boots directly into the raspbian gui without chromium starting

Comment: @coolblue2000 you will need to set your Pi back so it doesn't boot straight to desktop for this.

Comment: I have now set the pi back to not booting desktop in raspi-config. However now it boots to desktop and chromium still never appears. Now when I open a terminal window it crashes with an authentication error.